# Error handling in Node JS + Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am writing a small web-app using Node JS (version 8.4.0), Express (version 4.15.3) and using Passport (version 0.3.2) for authentication.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 for database.

I am not able to understand how to handle errors using Promises in my application.

I have divided my app into routes (has information related to which routes to handle via http requests), views (handlebars templates to render pages) and model (functions related to database queries).

Here is an example code from a model:

```
var helpers = require('./helpers'); //Has a function to perform db queries

exports.getCustomerDetails = (cust_id,cb)=>{

    var qs = 'select * FROM customers WHERE cust_id=($1)';
    var params = [cust_id];

    helpers.dbquery(qs,params,(error,results)=>{

        if(error){
            return cb(error);
        }

        return cb(null,results);

    });

}
```

At present, what I am doing in the corresponding route handler is to send HTTP 500 as response.

```
//Get Customer details based on cust_code as input

router.get('/getCustomerDetails',(req,res,next)=> {
    if (req.user) {

      var cust_code = req.query.value;

      db.getCustomerDetails(cust_code, (error, result) => {

        if (error) {
          res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        res.status(200).send(result);
      });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(401);
    }
})
```

I want to understand what is the best way to handle errors at both levels, i.e route and database.

I read a few articles on error handling and searched Stackoverflow, but I am not able to wrap my head around it being a beginner in any sort of development.

Please suggest how to handle errors in my web-app and any references which could help me understand error handling in web-apps.

Comment: The database should return errors back to the route.  The route should send an appropriate error status as the response if it gets back an error.  And, your code should send one and only one response per request (one of your routes above tries to send more than one response).  FYI, using promises instead of plain callbacks for all async operations will make propagation of errors back to the route much, much, much simpler, particular when there are multiple async operations involved in a given route.

Comment: Sorry if the code was not clear enough. The 401 response is sent if there is no valid user credentials to access the route. So there is only one response sent. I will explore the option of using promises in my project. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The following could do what you ask for. Create a promise, catch the reject of that promise and return the promise you created but not with the catch so the caller can catch the reject again.

```
var helpers = require('./helpers'); //Has a function to perform db queries

exports.getCustomerDetails = (cust_id, cb) => {
  var qs = 'select * FROM customers WHERE cust_id=($1)';
  var params = [cust_id];
  //create a promise
  const p = new Promise(
    (resolve,reject) =>
      helpers.dbquery(qs, params, (error, results) =>
        (error)
          ? reject(error)
          : resolve(results)
      )
  );
  //catch the reject
  p.catch(
    error => {
      //... do something with the error on the db level
    }
  );
  //return the promise that DID NOT have the error caught
  return p;
};


router.get('/getCustomerDetails',(req,res,next)=> {
  if (req.user) {
    var cust_code = req.query.value;
    //getCustomerDetails returns a promise
    db.getCustomerDetails(cust_code)
    .then(
      result =>
        res.status(200).send(result)
    )
    .catch(
      error =>
      res.sendStatus(500)
    )
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I have a query regarding the behavior of the code snippet below.                                                                                                              When i say "return p", is the error propagated to the caller or the result of the database query sent to the caller? I ask this as i am not sure if the error can be handled at db level.

Comment: @UmashankarVarma yes, as you can clearly see in the comments. if something goes wrong both the database function and express request handler get the error. What you do with the error is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the best way is to handle all errors in routes layer, in order to format them properly according to the interface. Imagine in the future you change your REST API layer by a GraphQL layer, with this approach you just have to modify this layer, and not the rest.
The way to throw all errors from other layers: I usually create an Error object and add several custom properties, for example:

```
var error = Error();
error.code = 401;
error.log = true;
error. translate = true;
error.message = "Unauthorized";
....
throw error;
```

And in the routes layer, you can catch the error and create the custom response with all the data. It is flexible and powerful.

Hope it helps.